# Invalid argument(s): onCreate must be null if no version is specified

Tags: flutter, sqlite, version

My code :

```
import 'package:apptour/basededatos/Empresa.dart';
import 'package:apptour/basededatos/Foto.dart';
import 'package:apptour/basededatos/Lugar.dart';
import 'package:apptour/basededatos/Ruta.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBmanager {
  // BASE

  static Future<Database> _openDb() async {
    return openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'apptuor'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE ruta(id INTEGER, nombre TEXT, urlfoto TEXT"
          "CREATE TABLE empresa(id INTEGER, razonsocial TEXT, descripcion TEXT, urllogo TEXT, ruta_id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER)"
          "CREATE TABLE lugar(id INTEGER, nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, urlfoto TEXT, latitud TEXT, longitud TEXT, ruta_id INTEGER)"
          "CREATE TABLE foto(id INTEGER, nombre TEXT, urlfoto TEXT, tipo INTEGER, lugar_id INTEGER)");
    });
  }

// métodos
// rutas
  Future<int> insertarRuta(Ruta modelo) async {
    var bd = await _openDb();

    return await bd.insert("ruta", modelo.toMap());
  }

  Future<List<Ruta>> obtenerRutas(String condicion) async {
    var basededatos = await _openDb();
    List<Map> lista =
        await basededatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ruta WHERE " + condicion);
    List<Ruta> rutas = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      rutas.add(
          new Ruta(lista[i]['id'], lista[i]['nombre'], lista[i]['urlfoto']));
    }
    return rutas;
  }

// EMPRESA
  Future<int> insertarEmpresa(Empresa empresa) async {
    var basedetados = await _openDb();
    int respuesta = await basedetados.insert("empresa", empresa.toMap());
    return respuesta;
  }

  Future<List<Empresa>> obtenerEmpresas(String condicion) async {
    var basededatos = await _openDb();
    List<Map> lista =
        await basededatos.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE " + condicion);
    List<Empresa> empresas = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      empresas.add(new Empresa(
        lista[i]['id'],
        lista[i]['razonsocial'],
        lista[i]['descripcion'],
        lista[i]['urllogo'],
        lista[i]['ruta_id'],
        lista[i]['user_id'],
      ));
    }
    return empresas;
  }

  Future<int> actualizarEmpresa(Empresa empresa) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    return await base.update("empresa", empresa.toMap(),
        where: 'id= ?', whereArgs: [empresa.id]);
  }

  Future<int> borrarTablaId(tabla, id) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    return await base.delete(tabla, where: 'id= ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // LUGAR
  Future<int> insertarLugar(Lugar lugar) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    int respuesta = await base.insert("lugar", lugar.toMap());
    return respuesta;
  }

  Future<List<Lugar>> obtenerLugares(String condicion) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    List<Map> lista =
        await base.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugar WHERE " + condicion);
    List<Lugar> lugares = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      lugares.add(new Lugar(
          lista[i]['id'],
          lista[i]['nombre'],
          lista[i]['descripcion'],
          lista[i]['urlfoto'],
          lista[i]['latitud'],
          lista[i]['longitud'],
          lista[i]['ruta_id']));
    }
    return lugares;
  }

  // FOTOS
  Future<int> insertarFoto(Foto foto) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    int respuesta = await base.insert("foto", foto.toMap());
    return respuesta;
  }

  Future<List<Foto>> obtenerFotos(String condicion) async {
    var base = await _openDb();
    List<Map> lista =
        await base.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foto WHERE " + condicion);
    List<Foto> fotos = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      fotos.add(new Foto(lista[i]['id'], lista[i]['nombre'],
          lista[i]['urlfoto'], lista[i]['tipo'], lista[i]['lugar_id']));
    }
    return fotos;
  }

  // delete
  Future<int> borrarTabla(String tabla) async {
```

The error appears in this part and it doesn't explain why I even did a validation to see if it was null :

```
      var base = await _openDb();
      return await base.rawDelete("DELETE FROM " + tabla);
    
  }
}
```

The error :

> ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): onCreate must be null if no version is specified)

Comment: Missing `)` on `CREATE TABLE ruta`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that no version is specified. The error is at the openDataBase method. You must insert the "version" value on this method, Initially it has value 1. The method must looks like this:

```
openDatabase(path, version: DB_VERSION, onCreate: _onCreate)
```